# How do I display the titles of all buttons that I click in a separate textfield or label

Tags: swift, xcode, methods

Currently I have a button that performs the task of displaying the title (in a textfield) of the button as well as printing it in the console. Right now I am only able to display the title of just one button that I click. Clicking another button will remove the title of the previous button and replace it with the title of the new button. How am I able to retain the titles of previous buttons i.e. clicking multiple buttons and displaying all of its titles one after the other in the textfield?

```
     import UIKit
    
    class GameScreenViewController: UIViewController {
        @IBOutlet weak var txtFieldUserAnswer: UITextField!
        @IBOutlet weak var answerTxtLabel: UITextField!

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            
            super.viewDidLoad()
    
            // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        }
        @IBAction func goBackBtn(_ sender: UIButton) {
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "GameScreenToHomeScreen", sender: self)
        }
        @IBAction func btn1Pressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
            print(sender.currentTitle!)
            answerTxtLabel.text = sender.currentTitle
            //Displays "1" in the answer text label.
        }
        
        @IBAction func btn2Pressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
            print(sender.currentTitle!)
            answerTxtLabel.text = sender.currentTitle
    
            //Displays a "2" in the answer text label.
        }
        
        @IBAction func btn3Pressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
            print(sender.currentTitle!)
            answerTxtLabel.text = sender.currentTitle
    
    
        }
        @IBAction func cancelBtn(_ sender: UIButton) {
            answerTxtLabel.text = nil

          //clears everything in the textfield
        }
        
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an `Array` to keep the titles

```
import UIKit

class GameScreenViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var txtFieldUserAnswer: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var answerTxtLabel: UITextField!

    var titles = [String]() {
       didSet {
           answerTxtLabel.text = titles.joined(separator: ", ")
       }
    }

    @IBAction func goBackBtn(_ sender: UIButton) {
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "GameScreenToHomeScreen", sender: self)
    }

    @IBAction func btn1Pressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        titles.append(sender.currentTitle!)
    }
    
    @IBAction func btn2Pressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        titles.append(sender.currentTitle!)   
    }
    
    @IBAction func btn3Pressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        titles.append(sender.currentTitle!)
    }

    @IBAction func cancelBtn(_ sender: UIButton) {
        titles.removeAll()
        //clears everything in the textfield
    } 
}
```

And you could use **one** `IBAction` for all three answer buttons.

Comment: I require my application to allow and show duplicates in the textfield, and secondly this code outputs my numbers in chronological order only. So for e.g. If i press button "3", "2" and "1" in that order the output I get is "123" instead of the desired output "321". I have taken your advice and linked my buttons with just one IBAction now.

Comment: Then an array is the better choice. See the edit

Comment: That helped quite a bit. The last bit i needed was to clear all data from the textfield and I think all data from the array too. I was able to clear the text from the textfield when I press the cancelBtn, however it seems the previous numbers are still stored in the array so it brings all the previous numbers back to the textfield in-spite of me clicking cancelBtn. Is there a way to go around this? E.g. pressing button "3", "2","1","CancelButton","3", "2", "1" gives me the output "321321" instead of desired output "321"

Comment: sorry my mistake i sorted it you were right